# StringGrid и авторазмер колонок под максимальную ширину

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Требуется настроить `StringGrid` так, чтобы при изменении ширины колонок, они автоматически подстраивались под установленную ширину области компонента.

В данный момент, при изменении размера колонок они уезжают за область, снимок я приложил ниже (смотреть на последнюю колонку (4 колонка) - Дата изменения)

Код, на автоматический подгон колонок под ширину области я написать смогу и сам (однако приму любые ваши мысли), но мне почему-то кажется, что у самого компонента уже должен быть какой-то параметр, который решит эту проблему и добавит новую ;)

Используется компонент `TAdvStringGrid` (Delphi XE2)

[image: Выезд за область выглядит так]

Comment: Документацию по этому компоненту искать не пробовали? Обычно все параметры и настройки описаны там.

Comment: Документацию посмотрел конечно, однако не смог найти в ней нужного мне свойства, их там конечно довольно много (посмотрел - пролистал ;))

Comment: А, если его действительно нет (надеюсь Вы смотрели внимательно)? На всякий случай можно посмотреть ещё у класса колонок. Но, в любом случае то чего нет в документации, скорее всего нет и в действительности.

Comment: Попробуйте метод AdvStringGrid1.AutoSizeColumns.. [источник](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/asg7.asp)